# getting error for opening MS word doc in IIS 7,

Tags: asp.net, iis, ms-word, .doc

I'm developing some pages by Asp.Net which contains opening and reading some MS word docs, it works well by my VS 2010 on its own localhost but when I put the files under wwwroot and run the pages by Inetmgr I get this error :

> This command is not available because no document is open.

where do you think the problem is? shall I add some references or edit some setting in my IIS manager to work with MS word docs? how? thanks :)

and this is how I'm trying to open and read a doc called stopwords.doc

```
static extractor()
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
            string[] words;
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', '\r', '\t', '\n' };
            string filePath =   "http://localhost:8777/stopwords.doc";
            object file = filePath;
            object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;                
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
            string m_Content = doc1.Content.Text;
            doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
            if (m_Content != null)
            {
                words = m_Content.Split(delimiterChars);
                foreach (string s in words)
                {
                    if (!stopwords.ContainsKey(s))
                        stopwords.Add(s, s);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: how do you open your document? can you show the code?

Comment: I either get docs from user to process or some already known files on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the accounts running web processes don't have enough os permissions to run GUI apps like Word. This is probably a good thing in most cases as one really shouldn't run GUI apps from web processes. What happens when word springs a modal dialog that blocks the entire site and no one is available to visit the web server and click OK. If you must read word docs, a library is a much better solution.

All that said, using word here makes zero sense -- you are just loading some stop words from a file. Plain text would be just as effective and vastly easier to deal with.

Comment: what about word files that user uploads? I'm trying to open them as well

Comment: See first paragraph, use appropriate library.

Comment: thanks, I tried DocX liberary, but it only works for Word 2007, do you think I can add the permission to let it to use word? I'm developing some prototype and there is no money to buy licenses for libraries like Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath =   "http://localhost:8777/stopwords.doc";
```

this is not a valid filepath.

try to put the file inside the web application folder, for example create a folder called WordDocs inside the place where you deployed your ASP.NET application then get the file path like this:

```
string filePath = Server.MapthPath("~/WordDocs/stopwords.doc");

if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
  object file = filePath;
  object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but I changed to this : string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/stopwords.doc"); and I still get the same error